# I'd like to change the link for the spotify logo in an embedded iframe playlist

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, spotify

I'm using this embedded iframe in my website (www.thatgolda.com):

playlist

[image: playlist]

The circled logo, when clicked, goes to a link that automatically downloads spotify. I'd like to know if there's some code I can use to change that link to my spotify artist page.

I'm not very familiar with javascript, so I'd appreciate an answer "for dummies."

Thanks in advance for your help.
GP

Answer (score 0):

From the Spotify Play Button website (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/):

> Is there any way of customizing the design of the Spotify Play Button?
>   E.g. color, typography…
>
> Currently there is no way no change the design of the Spotify Play
>   Button.

You can, however, use a Spotify Follow Button elsewhere on your website! The design is familiar for many users and clearly shows what the action of the button is. 
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-follow-button/
[image]